# Convert a simple list with fetched items to SwiftUI

Tags: list, foreach, swiftui, completion

I am converting a list I have with fetched items thru a completion block to a SwiftUI list. Here is what I am currently working with:

```
struct MoreView: View {
    
    private let seasonArray = [Season]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(seasonArray, id:\.self) { season in
                Text(season.name)
            }
         }
     }

    private mutating func fetchSeasons() {
        ContentManager().getSeasons() { response in
            seasonArray = response.sorted { $0.year < $1.year }
            // Reloaded tableview in UIKit here
        }
    }
}
```

What is the best practice to populate the list with the `seasonArray` var after `fetchSeasons()` runs and returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the `@State` property wrapper for seasonArray and give it an empty default value.
When you call the `fetchSeasons` function it should reload automatically your view without the need to implicitly reload because SwiftUI listens for changes for the seasonArray as an `@State` property.

You should instantiate the `ContentManager` once, as a constant.

```
struct MoreView: View {
    
    private let contentManager = ContentManager()
    @State private var seasonArray: [Season] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(seasonArray, id:\.self) { season in
                Text(season.name)
            }
         }
     }

    private func fetchSeasons() {
        contentManager.getSeasons() { response in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.seasonArray = response.sorted { $0.year < $1.year }
                // Reloaded tableview in UIKit here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That all makes sense. Where do I initially call `fetchSeasons()` though?

Comment: Figured out a way. I call `.onAppear { self.fetchSeason() } on the List.

Comment: Yes, that works. You can also call `fetchSeasons()` inside a custom initializer too.